# Why does the preview of site on Cloudflare worker differs from the browser?

Tags: browser, cloudflare-workers

I have a domain `A.tk` in the Cloudflare, and I have a server that cannot use the port 80 with domain `A.top`. The only way to visit `A.top` is `A.top:61445`, so I try to `fetch('A.top:61445')` in Cloudflare worker, and change the response when visiting `A.tk`. Everything is OK in the worker but not in the browser, where is the problem?Is it might cause of ICP?(I haven't get it)

```
async function handleRequest(request) {
  if(request.url.toString().indexOf('learn')!=-1)
  {
    let path = request.url.replace('.tk/', '.top:61445/')
    path = path[-1]=='/'?path:path+'/'
    let real = fetch(path)
    console.log(real.url)  //why is undefined
    return real
  }
  else
  {
    let path = request.url.replace('.tk/', '.top/')
    return fetch(path)
  }
}
addEventListener('fetch', async event => {
  event.respondWith(handleRequest(event.request))
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cloudflare doesn't allow such port...